# php array concat in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a string of numbers separated by `:` like `"20:1:21,21:0:21"`, this php code explodes the strings with `,` and and concatenate the resulting arrays into an associative array like:

```
$in = "20:1:21,21:0:21";
$list=explode(",",$in);
$results = array( 0 => array(), 1 => array());
foreach ($list as $item) {
        $item=explode(":",$item);
        if (sizeof($item)==3) {
            $results[$item[1]][$item[0]] += $item[2];
        }
    }
```

note the `+=` operator here.

The expected value of

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [21]=>
    int(21)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [20]=>
    int(21)
  }
}
```

or `[{"21":21},{"20":21}]` as json output.

In javascript it could be like

```
    var results = { 0: [], 1: [] };
    for (var key in list) {
        var item = list[key];
        item=item.split(":");
        if (item.length == 3) {
            if(!results[item[1]]) results[item[1]]={};
            results[item[1]][item[0]]=item[2];
        }
    }
```

but it creates a list of `null` values before appending the right values, why?

Comment: Please show us the expected output and the output you're getting. You should also show us what the `$in` variable contains.

Comment: You say you have a string, but then show code where apparently you have an array (`list`). Which is it? Please provide samples of the input (in JS format), the expected output for it and what you get.

Comment: added the expected output.

Comment: @Tschallacka just porting to code line by line.

Comment: _“note the += operator here”_ - note how you did something completely different in your JS …

Comment: @04FS right, what's wrong there?

Comment: If you replace `+=` with `=` it will produce the results you want.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson but I did `results[item[1]][item[0]]=item[2];` right?

Comment: Why would you define `results` as a plain object, when your desired result is an array?

Comment: @trincot just keep it as the original `php` code.

Comment: Data types are not completely comparable between PHP and JS. Associative arrays with numerical indexes translate best to JS arrays.

Comment: @trincot yes absolutely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JS code seems to expect an `array` as input, but your input is a string. Also, you define `result` as a plain object, but really want an array...

Here is how you can do it in JavaScript.

```js
var input = "20:1:21,21:0:21";

var result = input.split(",")
     .map(s => s.split(":"))
     .reduce((acc, [a,b,c]) => (acc[b] = {[a]: c}, acc), []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use Regex to accomplish it:

```js
var string = '20:1:21,21:0:21';
var regex = /(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/g;
var match;
var result = {};

while (match = regex.exec(string)) {
    result[match[2]] = {[match[1]]: match[3]};
}

console.log(result);
```